# Why is this Neo4j.query not returning results when using Neo4j::Rails::Model when cypher does?

Tags: neo4j

I am trying to do a simple test with Neo4j.rb using Neo4j::Rails::Models thats tag a single thing, then performs a query to find the thing again using the tag.

So data is essentially looks like this, with a single tag and a single thing:

(tag)-tags->(thing)

When I run the query using my script I don't get any results but if I use the webadmin console that comes with neo4j to run the equivalent query I get result as execpted.

I just can't figure out what I am doing wrong but I think it must be the way I am using the Neo4j.query block.

This is what I run from the console which gives the correct result.

```
neo4j-sh (0)$ START tag=node:Tag_exact(text='tag') MATCH tag-[:tags]->thing RETURN thing;

==> +------------------------------------------+
==> | thing                                    |
==> +------------------------------------------+
==> | Node[1]{name:"thing",_classname:"Thing"} |
==> +------------------------------------------+
==> 1 row
==> 197 ms
==> 
neo4j-sh (0)$
```

This is the test script which gives an equivalent cypher query but doesn't return any results.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'neo4j'
require 'fileutils'

# Create a new database each time
Neo4j::Config[:storage_path] = "test_neo"
FileUtils.rm_rf(Neo4j::Config[:storage_path])

# Models
class Tag < Neo4j::Rails::Model
    property :text, :index => :exact
end

class Thing < Neo4j::Rails::Model
    property :name
end

# Data
thing = Thing.new(:name => "thing")
thing.save

tag = Tag.new(:text => "tag")
tag.outgoing(:tags) << thing
tag.save

# Query
puts Neo4j::Cypher.query {
  lookup("Tag_exact", "text", "tag").outgoing(:tags).as(:thing)
}.to_s # START v1=node:Tag_exact(text="tag") MATCH (v1)-[:`tags`]->(thing) RETURN thing

results = Neo4j.query do
  lookup("Tag_exact", "text", "tag").outgoing(:tags).as(:thing)
end 

results.each do |result|
  p result["thing"]
end # nil, I want to get the name of thing back here
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the second last line, use symbol instead of string for accessing the result from the query.

```rb
result.each do |result|
  p result[:thing]
end
```

To know which columns are returned use the `columns` method, e.g.:

```rb
puts Neo4j.query { node(tag_id).outgoing(:tags).as(:thing) }.columns
```

Btw, remember that cypher query results are traversable only once.

Comment: Thanks Andreas. Really appreciated. Excellent work on the Neo4j gem.